# Razor MVC C #. Replaces the "." on ","

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Problem exists, razor replaces the value of the point (1.11) on the value of a comma (1,11)

It looks like the value:

[image]

But as displayed on the site:

[image]

Please tell me how to make that value was to the point, not a comma?

Comment: You should check the CultureInfo.

Comment: You are getting decimal separation as comma, it can be due to your culture info setting check what cultureinfo you are using.

Comment: It should be all right "ru-RU" but I do not care for the locus of a comma.

Comment: @SashaVasilev: You may not care about it, but **what about your users?** Because they need to understand those numbers. `0,66` seems fine to me in Russian.

Answer (score 4):

Seems that your current [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) is set to one that uses the comma as decimal separator.

To correct this, you can either force the CultureInfo for the whole application. In your `web.config` add:

One way to correct this is to force the culture infoSet this in your web.config

```
<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-US" />
```

Or set a different CultureInfo for the current request only:

```
var culture = new Globalization.CultureInfo("ru-RU", false);
culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator  = ".";
Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
```

Or a third possibility is to [provide a `IFormatProvider` argument to the `ToString` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cht2hdff.aspx):

```
@item.density.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Although it should be noted that changing separators **isn't recommended** because what developer prefers may not be exactly what users of a particular locale are used to... We should only change culture and keep settings as they are. In 99.9%.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik I totally agree with you! I would personally go with the third approach...

Answer (score 1):

ToString returns a human-readable string that is culture-sensitive. For example, for an instance of the Double class whose value is zero, the implementation of Double.ToString might return "0.00" or "0,00" depending on the current UI culture. Your name is Sasha Vasilev, so your UI culture will be ru-RU and decimal separator will be ',' not '.' . You need to do this:

```
@item.density.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
```